# connection && connection.close();

Tags: node.js, tedious

I'm reading some pieces of code using Node.js and Tedious to create a full-stack app connecting to MS SQL Server. And I stumbled upon this piece.

```
function createRequest(query, connection) {
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;
    var req =
        new Request(query, 
                function (err, rowCount) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.trace(err);
                            throw err;
                        }
                        connection && connection.close();
                        console.log('Connection closed');
                });
    return req;
}
```

Could anyone explain what the line
`connection && connection.close();`
does?

Comment: Remember to mark answers as accepted, if they helped you.

Answer (score 2):

`connection && connection.close()` is actually kind of a "trick" that I would not recommend.

It means

```
if (connection) {
  connection.close()
}
```

The trick is to use the `&&` operator as a shorthand syntax. If the left expression is falsy (`undefined` or `null` for exemple), the right expression won't even be evaluated.

You can give it a try with

```
true && console.log('Hello')
// 
false && console.log('will never be logged')
```

[There is a dedicated part about this short-circuit in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 1):

It is saying if `connection` is defined run `connection.close()`

it is the same as

```
if(connection){
    connection.close()
}
```

It works because `&&` returns the first Falsy result.

ie:

```
console.log(false && 'something'); // false

console.log(true && 'something'); // 'something'
```